# simple text chat server for old system (win2k) without node.js or other requirements

Tags: windows-2000

I am trying to find a web chat application (so as to be OS/device independent) to chat with family and friends. I do not mind to have great features and I do not need multi-user chat, but just 2.

I find different things with node.js, but the problem is that the static IP server I maintain is in a very old win2k system (for various reasons), and so installing node.js is not supported (?).
The server already runs a web server supporting html/javascript (but not PHP!), a teamtalk server and some other services. Teamtalk is fine but the old version that is supported on win2k does not have an android or huawei client, this is why I was thinking that a web-based solution would be great.

So I am looking for a web-based server with web based clients to make this chat system.
Needless to say that any solution that uses third party services are out of question.

Around 2000 I had found some java/flash web chats (that was the technology back then).
Any help on what I am trying to achieve, would be greatly appreciated.

I tried installing node.js but there were no win2k versions.

Comment: This seems to fulfill the purpose, but it requires long keys (encryption) one for each party https://github.com/michal-wrzosek/p2p-chat